# Is it possible to pause a stage until a time is reached in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to only allow deployments to production in a specific time range, e.g.: between 04:00 and 06:00.

My Jenkins pipeline is triggered by a Git webhook and starts a flow consisting of the usual stages (Build, Test, Deploy Dev, Deploy Pre, Deploy Pro).

When we reach the Deploy Pro stage I would need to check whether the current time is in the allows range to go on. Otherwise I need to pause the pipeline (**freeing the Jenkins agent**) until that time range is reached.

Is is possible to implement this? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you can use [sleep](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep) method, which can get different units: `NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS` (by default it's `SECONDS`).

E.g. `sleep(time:3,unit:"SECONDS")` (or just `sleep 3` - it's the same).

So, check whether the current time is in the allows range, and if it's not, then specify time for `sleep` method as value of `04:00 - <current time>` (you need to use some arithmetics here to get right value in seconds or minutes, but it shall be not hard).

But if all the other stages are quite fast, I recommend you to use `Poll SCM` option (with specifying time range) for all pipeline, because it's much more easier and the result will be the same - job will be finished only after 04:00.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins pipeline is triggered by a Git webhook and starts a flow consisting of the usual stages (Build, Test, Deploy Dev, Deploy Pre, Deploy Pro).

Option 1: 
skip the deployment using 'when' condition and if time is not between

Option 2: separate the pipelines for CI and CD And CD will trigger only during that or keep in pause stage using shell cmd